# Why the response time for web endpoint for WCF hosted on Azure Cloud Service is so long?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a WCF hosted on Azure Cloud Service. I added web endpoint to check if service is working correctly and the response times are terrible:[image]

Which I don't understand, because the polling I've done manually shows that service is responding much faster (please note that the times below are the times of whole call during which service is querying database on its side, the check itself should be faster):

[image]

And at the same time web endpoint of MVC website hosted completely the same and with the same configuration works great:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the endpoints, WCF Service didn't have HTTP endpoint. Adding one solved the problem.